# Failure to connect to Watson Platform

Tags: java, nlp, ibm-watson

I am having problems using the IBM Language Translator. I keep getting an java.net.ConnectException. My platform is Windows 10 and I am using Eclipse Photon. I have disabled my firewall and virus protection software. The following is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.LanguageTranslator;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.model.TranslateOptions;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.model.Translation;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.model.TranslationResult;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.util.Language;

class IBMTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LanguageTranslator service = new LanguageTranslator("2018-05-01");

        service.setApiKey("...apikey...");
        String textToTranslate = "Αυτοκινητόδρομος";
        List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
        text.add(textToTranslate);

        TranslateOptions translateOptions = new TranslateOptions.Builder().text(text).source(Language.GREEK)
                .target(Language.ENGLISH).build();
        TranslationResult firstResult = service.translate(translateOptions).execute();

        List<Translation> translations = firstResult.getTranslations();
        if (translations.size() > 1) {
            System.out.println("There are multiple translations:");
            for (Translation nextTranslation : translations) {
                System.out.println("- " + nextTranslation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The application throws an exception at:

```
TranslationResult firstResult = service.translate(translateOptions).execute();
```

The exception follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/54.209.159.70:443
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$WatsonServiceCall.execute(WatsonService.java:534)
    at com.packt.javanlp.cookbook.chapter.IBM.main(IBM.java:50)
    at com.packt.javanlp.cookbook.chapter.IBM.main(IBM.java:35)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/54.209.159.70:443
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$WatsonServiceCall.execute(WatsonService.java:531)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Where is your service/resource located? US? Germany? UK?

Comment: The service is located in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Does not seem to be a java problem. I just tested and tried to connect to your server via TCP:

```
telnet 54.209.159.70 443
.... connection timeout
```

I think you should check your settings- see https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/language-translator